# What is the best stone for the ring? (Shia View)

Tags: hadith, shiism

As a famous issue, it is named some stones as the best one for wearing the rings (for Fingers). Some of them are more famous and are declared as the best ones. Such as Firoozeh (turquoise), Aqiq (agate), Ruby, Dor of Najaf and so forth. I was wondering which one would be considered as the best one according to narrations (hadiths)?

***Note***: I am looking for the viewpoint of Shia, although Sunni’s viewpoint would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the Shia view the Aqiq as the first stone to have accepted the Willaya of Imam Ali (r.a.) and that would elevate it to the status of the best among the stones.

> Muhammed (p.b.u.h) has said whoever wears Aqeeq his wishes will be
>   fulfilled. A hadith from Janabe Salman Farsi(R.A) states that
>   Muhammed(p.b.u.h)requested Imam Ali to wear a ring on the right hand
>   so that he may be listed among the Muqarrabeen (those near to Allah
>   (S.W.T)). The Imam asked Muhammed(p.b.u.h) as to whom the Muqarrabeen
>   were, to which Muhammed (p.b.u.h) replied Janabe Jibreel and Janabe
>   Mikaiel. Then the Imam inquired as to which stone he should wear.
>   Muhammed(p.b.u.h) replied Aqeeq (cornelian), as this red stone had
>   accepted the oneness of Allah (S.W.T), the prophethood of Muhammed
>   (p.b.u.h), and the vicegerency of Ali ibn Abi Talib (R.A)

**Source:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akik

Comment: your answer would be finer if you add some source for it. In the meantime, I appreciate it dear mate. Good luck.

Comment: Uh-huh, at the moment your respond became so better than before by presenting the source and it deserve +1.  و من الله توفیق